# Execute command from file in current shell

Tags: command-line, scripts, execute-command

I want to executed command from file (which is script) in current shell in terminal.

Example: I have file `ch_dir` contains following:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /usr
```

Now if I execute file usually as following then it executes commands in **different shell**:

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ ./ch_dir
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$
```

Here `cd /user` is executed in different shell.

But I want to execute in Current shell. How do I do that?

**Note:** Here `cd` is only used to explain. Question's aim is to execute any **command in current shell**

Comment: @muru Questions are **not** same (it seems both answer using `source` )!

Comment: Questions are same, different motivations: How do I affect the calling shell from a script/file? Because of all the context, the noise added makes it unclear.

Comment: @muru yes but `source` is not limited to passing variable only.

Comment: That's just the example used. The general question, which neither of these questions have stated, is "How do I affect the calling shell from a script?" If you edit this question to reflect that I'd be happy to retract this close vote and flag the other. To me, both are dupes. Both of you are asking two specific forms of the same general problem.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use builtin command **`source`** (from `help -m source`):

> **source - Execute commands from a file in the current shell.**

Example of execution mentioned in Question:

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ source ch_dir
pandya@pandya-desktop:/usr$
```

Here you can see `cd /usr` is **executed in current shell** and hence directory of current shell changed!

Hope this will help to **execute command input from file in current shell.**

Comment: A common shorthand for `source` is `.`, as in @mehdy answer.

Comment: @Rmano `.` also works in more [Bourne-style shells](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell#Bourne_shell) than `source`, which is provided specially by [`bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/bash.1.html). For example, [`dash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/dash.1.html) (Ubuntu's default system `sh`) doesn't have `source`. (On the other hand, `source` works in some non-Bourne-style shells that don't use `.`, like [`csh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/bsd-csh.1.html) / [`tcsh`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/tcsh.1.html).)

Answer (score 5):

Just run the script with a `.` like this:

```
pandya@pandya-desktop:~$ . ./ch_dir
```